# Is there any event that fired before query goes to SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I want to find event, that fired before query goes to SQL Server. and do some changes at sql command before any data is retrieved from server.
Generally my goal is create an class that inherit some base ado.net class, where i can filter data before sql goes to server by addnig WHERE condition to the query. I need common deсision for all my application but not single case.

Comment: Not out of the box - the query goes to SQL Server when you issue `.ExecuteNonQuery` or something like that. But you *could* write a wrapper around the `SqlCommand` class and fire an event just *before* that call to `.ExecuteNonQuery` (or `.ExecuteReader`) to give your code a chance to handle that.

Answer (score 3):

ADO.NET supports the *decorator* pattern. Technically, you can create your own DbConnection subclass that wraps the *actual* connection, and apply your own changes just before passing along ExecuteScalar / ExecuteNonQuery / etc calls. Unfortunately the need to wrap the connection, command, parameters and reader makes this a bit awkward, bit look at "mini-profiler" for an example of this (it uses the pattern to provide instrumentation and logging).

However, a better approach here may be to tweek the upstream implementation. In many cases blindly adding a "where" will fail.